# Wordpress Access in Nginx and Permission denied

Tags: nginx, permissions, php-fpm, wordpress

I have been trying to get wordpress work with nginx its new task for me but I am almost done.
But I am still at the end can't get wordpress to work I have tried everything I was able to get and the same issue exactly and the solution  approved, but didn't work for me.

```
017/01/28 10:54:22 [crit] 3576#3576: *65 stat() "/home/wptask/public_html/wp-admin/install.php" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: firtswebsite.com, request: "GET /wp-admin/install.php HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1"
2017/01/28 10:53:36 [crit] 3576#3576: *1 stat() "/home/wptask/public_html/wp-admin/install.php" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 192.168.10.1, server: firtswebsite.com, request: "GET /wp-admin/install.php HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.10.10"
```

I did this

```
chmod +x /home
chmod +x /home/wptask
chmod +x /home/wptask/public_html 
sudo chown -R wptask:wptask /home/wptask
chmod go-rwx /home/wptask
chmod go+x /home/wptask
chgrp -R wptask /home/wptask
chmod -R go-rwx /home/wptask
chmod -R g+rx /home/wptask
chmod -R g+rwx /home/wptask
```

and even `chmod 755 /home/wptask`

but non works for me

Update :-
ls -l  for the webroot

```
[root@web-srv ~]# ls -l /home/wptask/
drwxr-sr-x. 2 root root   41 Jan 30 07:01 logs
drwxr-sr-x. 5 root root 4096 Jan 28 08:41 public_html
```

nginx.conf

```
    user  nginx;
    worker_processes  1;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Fix Update :-

ls -l  webroot

```
[root@web-srv ~]# ls -l /home/wptask/
total 4
drwxr-s---. 2 wptask wptask   41 Jan 30 07:01 logs
drwxr-s---. 5 wptask wptask 4096 Jan 28 08:41 public_html
```

and i changed the nginx user in nginx.conf

Comment: Have you checked SELinux? I hope you also have reverted all the changes you have made to permissions that haven't worked correctly.

Comment: SELinux disabled , as for now all the same , its test lab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file permissions will be incorrect with respect to the user Nginx is running as. You haven't given us enough information to help, like who nginx runs as ( ps -u | grep nginx ) or where things are stored.

I have a tutorial that should help, [here](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-2-setting-up-aws-for-wordpress-with-rds-nginx-hhvm-php-ssmtp/#fp). Key parts are

```
useradd tim   (NB: you can name the user something else if you like!)
passwd tim    (NB: give them a secure password, but you'll never need to use it)
groupadd www-data
usermod -a -G www-data nginx   (add the nginx user to the www-data group)
chown -R tim /usr/share/nginx/
chgrp -R www-data /usr/share/nginx/
chmod -R 750 /usr/share/nginx/
chmod -R g+s /usr/share/nginx/
```

This is based on the [Wordpress permissions documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions).

Comment: Thank you Tim, the problem solved , only after  do 777 for each path , i am sure something is wrong with me and i know where is it, thanks for your helpful link and advice :)

Comment: 777 "anyone can do anything" is not a solution, it's opening up the file permissions so wide any process or user can do anything. I encourage to keep looking at the problem.

Comment: It works only with 755. i have tested it with less with no luck.

Comment: Your file ownership is incorrect with respect to your web server user. You haven't given the requested information so I can't help further.

Comment: here is the output:   [root@web-srv ~]# ps -u | grep nginx 
root      4054  0.0  0.0 112648   960 pts/0    S+   06:29   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx

Comment: You really need to read a good tutorial and documentation on this. Change the Nginx user to something other than root, then you need to ensure that user has appropriate access to the webroot).

Comment: The user your nginx runs as is in your nginx.conf, see the user directive. Perhaps you could edit your question to include the nginx.conf and and ls -l of your webroot